# Receiving a ValueError: Unknown level when running GoogleScraper

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I recently decided to get to grips with some python and try to learn my way around the language but i've inevitably ran into a couple of problems that I was hoping someone could help me with.

Basically, I'm running on an OSx machine, I uninstalled the python that came with the operating system and used HomeBrew to download python 3.5.2, all that went successfully. Next I installed GoogleScraper (https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper) which went well after a couple tries, but now, when I try to run a test query through terminal:

```
GoogleScraper -m http --keyword "apple" -v2
```

After the machines whizzes and buzzes for a few seconds, it pops out with an error:

```
 GoogleScraper -m http --keyword "apple" -v2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/GoogleScraper", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/GoogleScraper/core.py", line 173, in main
    setup_logger(level=config.get('log_level').upper())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/GoogleScraper/log.py", line 23, in setup_logger
    logger.setLevel(level)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1255, in setLevel
    self.level = _checkLevel(level)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 187, in _checkLevel
    raise ValueError("Unknown level: %r" % level)
ValueError: Unknown level: '2'
```

I've been trying to learn python online and am making some progress, but for the life of me can't figure out what any of that error means, hopefully one of you could at least point me in the direction of a solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is that the full error message? If not, could you post the whole thing?

Comment: Hi elethan, thanks for the reply, just updated my question to include all the code from the request to the end. Thanks!

Comment: just a tip since you are new to the site: when you want to direct a comment to a user use the "@" symbol before their name. Otherwise they will not get a notification and may not see your comment ;) Glad your issue got solved! I don't know why it doesn't work as in the example on their site...

Comment: @elethan, thanks will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the source](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper/blob/master/GoogleScraper/log.py), the logging level is a string that corresponds to a [syslog severity level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level), not a number indicating level of verboseness.  This appears to work:

```
GoogleScraper -m http --keyword "apple" -v INFO
```

Comment: I don't doubt that your solution works, but the `-v2` comes from the GoogleScraper docs in the QuickStart section.

Comment: Hi Lex, yes that works for me as well! thank you very much and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Hi elethan, yeah thats true, do you know why this method works but not the one proposed by the developer?

Comment: i opened an issue: [https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper/issues/160](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper/issues/160)

Comment: @LexScarisbrick, thanks for your help, much appreciated